# Visual Studio getting confused about Python versions

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, environment-variables

I am calling a simple Python script from a C# file as

```
        //ADD results and errors  e.g., code Run GP tool.sln
        #region Running Python scripts Commented
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        //Script variables, paths etc.
        psi.FileName = @"C:\Users\oguz\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone1\python.exe";
        var py_script = @"C:\Users\oguz\source\repos\ProAppModuleDeneme5\ShapefileProcess\ShapefileProcess.py"; //change the path later
        var filename_old = shp_path;
        var filename_new = shp_path.Remove(21) + "F" + RenameTextBox.Text;
        psi.Arguments = $"{py_script} {filename_old} {filename_new}";
        MessageBox.Show(psi.Arguments);
        //Process configuration
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        //Execute and get output
        var errors = "";
        var results = "";

        using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(errors);
            MessageBox.Show(results);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(errors);
        Console.WriteLine(results);
```

This C# code supposed to call A Python code as

```
import arcpy
import sys
import os



filename_old = sys.argv[1]
filename_new = sys.argv[2]

folder_path = "C:\\Projects\\Test"

arcpy.env.workspace = folder_path

arcpy.Rename_management(str(filename_old), str(filename_new))
```

I get this message

[image]

It looks like Visual Studio calls the right Python then when a library needed it is trying to get it from different Python environment.

I have tried so many things but result is the same.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the other Python versions and kept the one I need then it worked fine. I think those Python versions came with Visual Studio. That was the only way I was able to work it out. Hopefully, someone will give better answer.